# NodeJS MySQL API cannot create Users from JSON

Tags: mysql, node.js, api

First of all, this is the repo website: https://github.com/TheFJS14/ck-app (you can see all code related to)

I am developing a NodeJS RESTful API with MySQL but, when I am trying to post a new User json, it report an error:

```
ReferenceError: User is not defined
    at exports.create (C:\...\app\controllers\user.controller.js:10:18)
```

This is my file:

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: "Content can not be empty!"
        });
    }
                 vvvvvvvvv
    const user = new User({
        nameUser: req.body.nameUser,
        emailUser: req.body.emailUser
    });

    User.create(user, (err, data) => {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the user."
            });
        else res.send(data);
    });
};
```

I have other code references:

```
const UserRole = require("../models/userRole.model.js");

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body) {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: "Content can not be empty!"
        });
    }

    const userRole = new UserRole({
        nameUserRole: req.body.nameUserRole,
        descriptionUserRole: req.body.descriptionUserRole
    });

    UserRole.create(userRole, (err, data) => {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the user role."
            });
        else res.send(data);
    });
};
```

When I move my mouse over my User model, I get this message:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wjwf.png

But, when I see other codes, it looks different with my mouse over them: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqsOR.png

> I probably need to change my variable name, but I prefer not.
> Thanks!

Comment: what is ur line `10` in ur `user.controller.js` ??

Comment: @Panther I marked it with "v"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code in github, in `user.controller.js` you have added this line:

> const UserRole = require("../models/user.model.js");

you have to change it to

> const User = require("../models/user.model.js");

That's why it throws and Error that *User is not defined*